# RavenDB Map-Reduce Example using .NET Client

Tags: .net, mapreduce, ravendb

I'm looking for an example of how to implement and use Map-Reduce within the RavenDB .NET Client.

I'd like to apply it to a specific scenario: generating unique and total visitor counts.

A sample document that would be stored within RavenDB:

```
public class StatisticsEntry
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I can figure out how to create a standard index using Map, but I'm lost as to how to actually use the Reduce function, and then retrieve the results.

Unfortunately, the [example provided on the RavenDB Site](http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-http-indexes-map-reduce) doesn't explain what's going on so that I can understand how to use it via the .NET API, and the samples don't seem to implement this at all using the .NET API.

Comment: What are you wanting to achieve? Are you wanting to use the date time in any way? (Per day, per month, per year kinda things?)

Comment: Not at present. I may have additional indexes at a later time using this field. For the moment, I'll remove it from the class to simplify. As for "Wanting to achieve" - I want to generate statistics showing a) Total count of StatisticsEntry and b) Unique Users.

Comment: Okay - because you would need one map/reduce index per 'grouping' in that sort of scenario -  answer coming up in a jiffy

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A map reduce index is just another way of saying "I want to do a group by", only the group by is pre-defined up front and RavenDB will process it in an efficient manner in the background so at query time you are looking up a pre-calculated result.

Consider the following as an answer as an ordinary group by (for unique users)

```
 var results = from doc in docs
 group doc by doc.UserId into g
 select new
 {
      g.UserId,
      g.Count()
 }
```

Ignoring the actual contents of the created array, we can get the total results by asking for

```
 results.Length
```

as you'd expect.

In RavenDB, you split out this function into a Map and a Reduce, and you end up with

```
public class UniqueVisitorsResult
{
     public string UserId { get; set; }
     public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class UniqueVisitorsIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<StatisticsEntry, UniqueVisitorsResult>
{
    public UniqueVisitorsIndex ()
    {
        Map = docs=> from doc in docs
                         select new 
                         { 
                             UserId = doc.UserId, 
                             Count = 1 
                         };
        Reduce = results => from result in results
                        group result by result.UserId into g
                        select new 
                        { 
                            UserId = g.Key, 
                            Count = g.Sum(x=>x.Count) 
                        };
    }
}
```

In essence, this is the same as the above - but you've turned it into a MapReduce function ;-)

```
 session.Query<StatisticEntry, UniqueVisitorsIndex>().Count();
```

Will give you the total number of unique visitors, assuming Count has been implemented properly in the LINQ provider (iirc I think it has)

The total number of entries is simply

```
 session.Query<StatisticEntry>().Count();
```

As you'd expect (No map/reduce required)

Note: this index can also be used to see the number of hits by a specific user, as the Count is being calculated in the index, if you don't care about the count then drop that part of the MapReduce and do

```
public class UniqueVisitorsIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<StatisticsEntry>
{
    public UniqueVisitorsIndex ()
    {
        Map = docs=> from doc in docs
                     select new 
                     { 
                         UserId = doc.UserId
                     };
        Reduce = results => from result in results
                    group result by result.UserId into g
                    select new 
                    { 
                        UserId = g.Key
                    };
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first example you provide `Count = g.Sum(x=>x.Count)` - this gives me a compilation error as `x` is of type `StatisticsEntry` - where's this supposed to come from?

Comment: Oh, define an output shape, let me modify the example :)

Comment: And the key to installing this index? `Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(UniqueVisitorsIndex).Assembly, documentStore);` -- took me a bit of digging to find that one. :)

Comment: What do you mean: "Oh, define an output shape"?
Could you give an example of what StatisticsEntry looks like?  
Is it the model of doc in docs in the first example?

Answer (score 18):

Here is how you can build an index for unique visitors:

```
public class Statistics_UniqueVisitors : AbstractIndexCreationTask<StatisticsEntry>
{
    public Statistics_UniqueVisitors()
    {
        Map = entries => from entry in entries
                         select new { entry.UserId, Count = 1 };
        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.UserId into g
                            select new { UserId = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(x=>x.Count) };
    }
}
```

You can then query this using:

```
var numberOfUniqueVisitors = s.Query<StatisticEntry, Statistics_UniqueVisitors>().Count();
```

For total count of visitors, you can use:

```
var numberOfVisitors = s.Query<StatisticEntry>().Count();
```