# RavenDB Map/Reduce over property that is a list

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb

Just learning Map/Reduce and I'm missing a step. I've read this post ( [RavenDB Map-Reduce Example using .NET Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253334/ravendb-map-reduce-example-using-net-client) ) but can't quite make the jump to what I need.

I have an object:

```
public class User : IIdentifiable
{
    public User(string username)
    {
        Id = String.Format(@"users/{0}", username);
        Favorites = new List<string>();
    }

    public IList<string> Favorites { get; protected set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is get Map/Reduce the Favorites property across all Users. Something like this (but this obviously doesn't work):

```
 Map = users => from user in users
                from oil in user.Favorites
                select new { OilId = oil, Count = 1 };
 Reduce = results => from result in results
                     group result by result.OilId into g
                     select new { OilId = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count) };
```

For example, if User1 has favorites 1, 2, 3 and User 2 has favorites 1,2, then this should return back {{OilId=3, Count =1}, {OilId=2, Count = 2}, {OilId=1,Count = 2}}

The current code produces an exception:  System.NotSupportedException : Node not supported: Call

I feel like I'm close. Any help?

Comment: What results do you get back, if you query against that Map/Reduce index where "Count > 0" what values do you get back?

Comment: The code supplied for the Map/Reduce produces an error when run:  System.NotSupportedException : Node not supported: Call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a small application replicating your code, but I don't see the exception thrown. See my code here: http://pastie.org/2308175. The output is

> Favorite: 1, Count: 2
>
> Favorite: 2, Count: 2
>
> Favorite: 3, Count: 1

which is what I would expect.

Comment: Yes, after looking it over we've got the same code. The problem I had was that I had a Select added to my RavenDB IQueryable object. I called a ToList first and then called the select and all works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

MBonig,
Map/Reduce is only useful for doing aggregation *across* documents. For something like this, you would be served far better by doing something like:

```
  session.Query<User>().Select(u=>u.Favorites).ToList()
```

Comment: I thought that is what I was trying to do. I guess I wasn't clear in the OP. I want to aggregate and find out what values in all the Users' Favorites list are the most selected.